# ember-cp-validations: Validation on htmlbar does not work

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frameworks, frontend

---

My problem is that the validation on the htmlbar `new.hbs` does not work. 
It is so confused for me, because I have a basic Ember project. I went through the [tutorial](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations) on github step by step and it just does not work.

---

What I've done is that:

- add `Validations` variable to `rental.js` model
- add helper `v-get` to `new.hbs`

I should be grateful if you could help me figure out why it does not work.

[This is](https://github.com/maximdeveloper/study_ember) my project on github.
Version of Ember that I used is  `2.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the route model.

You need to pass an object model to the validation helper, but in you route you are doing findAll, which is returning an array of objects, so you cant pass that in.

What you can do, in this case, is instead of doing findAll, do 

`model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('rental');
}`

Then you will see your validations, because now the model is just one object.